# Pytest/Mock keeping around extra object references in case of caught exceptions

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, reference-counting, del

I am running into a strange issue using pytest and mock: I am trying to create a call to `__del__` by deleting an object using `del ...`. According to the documentation, `del` only reduces the reference counter on the object that is being "deleted" and only actually deletes the object if nobody else is still holding a reference to it. It seems like if Mock throws an exception, that somehow leads to someone grabbing and keeping an extra reference to the object.

I put together a quick demo test to show the issue: The only difference between `test_del_passes` (which completes just fine) and `test_del_fails` (which fails with the last assertion, i.e. `del del_test` does not cause a call to `del_test.__del__()`) is that in the first one, `test_fn` returns a value, whereas in the second one, `test_fn` throws a `TimeoutError`. I tried deleting the `test_fn` object, or assigning `TimeoutError` to a variable instead and deleting that, but I simply can't find a way to get the second test to pass. So somewhere in the testing infra, someone is keeping an extra reference to `del_test` and I don't know who or why or how to get rid of it.

```
import unittest.mock as mock

class DelTest:
    def __init__(self, flags, test_fn):
        self.flags = flags
        self.test_fn = test_fn

    def __del__(self):
        self.flags[0] = 1

    def run(self):
        try:
            self.test_fn()
        except TimeoutError:
            pass


def test_del_passes():
    flags = [0]
    test_fn = mock.Mock(side_effect=[True])
    del_test = DelTest(flags, test_fn)
    del_test.run()
    assert flags[0] == 0
    del del_test
    assert flags[0] == 1


def test_del_fails():
    flags = [0]
    test_fn = mock.Mock(side_effect=[TimeoutError()])
    del_test = DelTest(flags, test_fn)
    del_test.run()
    assert flags[0] == 0
    del del_test
    assert flags[0] == 1
```

Answer (score 3):

The frame keeps a reference to the object, which you can see invoking `gc.get_referrers(del_test)`:

```
[<frame at 0x101b15080, file 'xxx.py', line 17, code run>]
```

Comment: That's a super helpful command! Thank you! For me, the line shown corresponds to the `pass` line in the `except` block (or, more precisely, the first line in the `except` block, even if I insert something before `pass` there). I still don't think I fully understand what's going on, especially since changing it to `except TimeoutError as e: del e` doesn't fix the issue either. In fact, more strangely, what does fix the issue is replacing `side_effect=[TimeoutError()]` with `side_effect=[TimeoutError]`, i.e. dropping the parentheses...